# How to apply "Diff()" methode to multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply diff() method to multiple columns to make data Stationary for time series.

> > > x1 = frc_data['004L004T10'].diff(periods=8)
> > >       x1
> > >       Date
> > >       2013-10-01   NaN

2013-11-01   NaN

2013-12-01   NaN

2014-01-01   NaN

2014-02-01   NaN
So diff is working for single column.

However diff is not working for all the columns:

for x in frc_data.columns:

```
   frc_data[x].diff(periods=1)
```

No errors, although the Data remains Unchanged

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: i am not getting any errors but the dataframe remains unchanged

Comment: Please add that important detail to your question!

Answer (score 0):

In order to *change* the DataFrame, you need to assign the diff to a new column i.e.

```py
for x in frc_data.columns:
    frc_data[x] = frc_data[x].diff(periods=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop is not necessary, only remove `[x]` for difference of all columns:

```
frc_data = frc_data.diff(periods=1)
```